# C# errors while repeatedly calling a function

Tags: c#

I have a problem with the following code :

```
 class Program
{
    public static void Progress(ProgressEventArgs e)
    {
        int result = e.getPartialResult;
        int stack_value = e.getValue ;
        double max = System.Convert.ToDouble(numbers[j]);
        System.Convert.ToDouble(stack_value);
        double percent = (stack_value / max) * 100;

        Console.CursorLeft = 18;
        Console.Write(result + " ");
        Console.CursorLeft = 46;
        Console.Write(System.Convert.ToInt32(percent) + "%      ");

    }
    public static void Calculate(int number, int time=0)
    {

        Factorial Fact = new Factorial();
        Fact.Progression += new Factorial.ProgressEventHandler(Progress);
        Console.Write("\n" + "Partial results : ");
        Console.CursorLeft = 35;
        Console.Write("Progress : ");         
        int Result = Fact.CalculateFactorial(number, time);
        Console.WriteLine(" ");
        Console.WriteLine("The factorial of " + number + " is : " + Result);


        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static int j;
    static int[] numbers;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i=0;
        bool ok = false;
        numbers = new int[10];
        Console.Write("Please insert wait time (0,1 or 2) : ");
        int time = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) * 1000;
        Console.Write("Please insert a number : ");
        do
            if (Console.ReadLine() != "")
            {
                i++;
                numbers[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


            }
            else
            {
                ok = true;
            }
        while (ok == false);
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {

            Calculate(numbers[j],time);
        }

    }
}
```

So things are a bit strange here... and it seems to come from the  if(Console.Readline()!="") condition.

So this program is supposed to calculate the factorial of several numbers. I give it a delay time in order to diplay the stack progress through percentage.

If I enter a random time and insert only two values the program will work, but only for the first number. If i enter more than 2 numbers I will get FormatException unhandled.

Now if I replace the condition with if(numbers[i]!=10) the program will work for any number of values, but 10! must be calculated.

How do I handle this problem? Am I missing something obvious?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's quite a lot of code for a question. If possible, try to shrink it down to a minimal example showing the problem. Also please include the exact position where the `FormatException` was thrown.

Comment: To make things easier, try using "try { } catch (Exception err){ }" around your code. That enables you to provide more Information about Errors you get. In the "catch" block you can output information to the console.

Comment: As stated below = make sure your arrays always start at index position 0 and not one.   array[0] is the correct starting point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'are reading the line twice. Change the code like this:

```
string line = string.Empty;
do
{
    line = Console.ReadLine();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
    { 
       numbers[i] = int.Parse(line);
       i++;
    }
    else
    {
      ok = true;
    }

}while (!ok && i<10);
```

*Should* work for you.

Answer (score 1):

The While loop is waiting to break. 
Something like the below would be good

```
....
string inputString;
while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputString = Console.ReadLine()) && i < numbers.Length)
{
   numbers[i] = int.Parse(inputString);
   i++;
}
```

Comment: while correct and nifty, in my opinion Tigran's code is a lot easier to understand and more readable. Especially for an obvious newbie...

Comment: Yes his answer is a good one. I couldn't stop myself from refactoring this unitl it looked good enough for me